# Retrieve Anchor Text To Use In Title Text

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I'm attempting to use JavaScript to retrieve the text between the opening and closing anchor tags, so I can add it to the title tag. I have thousands of links and nineteen plugins to which I need add a title tag and I'd really rather not have to go do this manually. Plus, you know, messing with a third-party plugin really isn't a good idea.

I've been searching this for about two hours. Between StackOverflow and Google the closest I've come is the code below. It partially works, but the title tag reads undefined. I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

```js
var linktext = document.getElementsByTagName('a').textContent;
var titletext = ['a', 'input', 'select', 'button', 'textarea'];

for (var i = 0; i < titletext.length; i++) {
  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName(titletext[i]);
  for (var j = 0; j < elem.length; j++) {
    elem[j].setAttribute('title', linktext);
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Some Link Text</a>
<a href="#">More Link Text</a>
<a href="#">Further Link Text</a>
<a href="#">Last Link Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var linktext = document.getElementsByTagName('a').textContent;
```

This is undefined. Here  textContent property is not defined, just because you have multiple 'a' tags.

```js
/*var linktext = document.getElementsByTagName('a').textContent;*/

var titletext = ['a', 'input', 'select', 'button', 'textarea'];

for (var i = 0; i < titletext.length; i++) {
  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName(titletext[i]);
  for (var j = 0; j < elem.length; j++) {
    /*elem[j].setAttribute('title', linktext);*/
    elem[j].setAttribute('title', elem[j].textContent);
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Some Link Text</a>
<a href="#">More Link Text</a>
<a href="#">Further Link Text</a>
<a href="#">Last Link Text</a>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much! I'll mark it right, as soon as six minutes are up.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the value of `linktext` to the `textContent` property of the Node List of all `a` elements.

Node Lists don't have `textContent`. You need to read it from a specific element.

Given your HTML you might want `var linktext = elem[j].textContent` … but that wouldn't work for the `input`, `select` or `textarea` elements you have in your list.

It isn't clear where you want to copy the data from.

---

This does sound like a really bad idea in the first place though. You seem to be trying to duplicate that text content of elements in the title attribute which seems entirely redundant (horribly so in the case of screen readers which will read out the text content and the (identical) title!)

Comment: I know for accessibility it's a terrible choice, but the choice isn't mine in the least.